# Pass serialzable object or query database again?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serializable

I have a FoodObject instantiated on MainActivity. I'd like to show EditActivity, where FoodObject populates the appropriate fields on the EditActivity and is ready to be edited.

I see two options:
(1) Pass EditActivity the _id of the FoodObject and have it query the db to get the FoodObject using Loader, etc.
- OR - 
(2) Pass EditActivity the FoodObject directly as a serializable using intent.putExtra().

I'm very new to Android/Java (many years of obj-c, though), so I'm not sure what is best practice.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to pass in the ID of the object and then re-query it in EditActivity.  You should also stay away from `Serializable` whenever possible as it does not perform very well (see http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/).

Comment: Thanks James! This is kind of what I assumed. I'll definitely checkout the link.

Comment: @James McCracken Im pretty sceptical about that article you posted. 
In Android you'll use Serialisable when passing an object from one Activity to another. The article states that the process of bundling and unbundling a serializable would take 4ms on a Desire Z. What tjhe heck does it matter when the transition from one Activity to another will take 500ms on that device (just a guess)? 

Also, what makes you think querying a DB will be faster than stated 4ms?

Comment: The bundling and unbundling will happen on the UI thread along with whatever other logic you are running.  That's an extra 4ms closer you are to the 17ms threshold for dropping your 60fps UI and giving your end user a choppy experience.  Querying the database may take a littler longer, actually, but that query can be done off of the UI thread.